# recognize when android rfcomm lost connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wish to gracefully handle the case when my Bluetooth device temporarily (a GPS logger) goes out of range, for example when I have been happily communicating and I accidentally go behind a wall. In this case, the connection is lost and has to be re-established, but I can't find how to recognize that it's lost. The data is being "pushed" from the device and can quite validly have delays in the data packets. 
 
The

```
 socket.isConnected()
```

function returns true even when I switch the device off.
I would hope there's a property of the controller stack protocol which has to maintain the radio channel, but I haven't found if/how to access it.
I know I could implement an ACK/NACK in a timer loop, but it seems a bit like re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had done in the past it to try to get input stream from the socket. If it is not connected it would get you some exceptions. In that case, you would know that the connection is lost since you are not getting any message back from the bluetooth device.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the approach used in the examples I've seen - like BloetoothChatService. I just looks a bit unreliable. But maybe that's the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: The approach used in BluetoothChatService, of a try/catch around  mmInStream.readMessage doesn't raise an exception when the connection drops.

Comment: Correction. Yes, an attempt to read() on the Input Stream when not connected does throw an IOException.